# Yii2 Dropzone.js init not working

Tags: php, yii, dropzone.js, yii2-advanced-app

I'm  using yii2 with dropzonejs (perminder-klair/yii2-dropzone)

When i want to initialize the view with some data i got this error,
It seems like the init call is not proccessed

### error

```
dropzone.min.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: this.options.init.call is not a function
    at c.init (dropzone.min.js:1)
    at new c (dropzone.min.js:1)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (index.php?r=branches/upload:672)
    at fire (jquery.js:3187)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:3317)
    at Function.ready (jquery.js:3536)
    at HTMLDocument.completed (jquery.js:3552)
```

## my dropzonejs

```
 <?= \kato\DropZone::widget([
        'autoDiscover' => false,
       'options' => [
         'init' => "function(file){alert( ' is removed')}",
         'url'=> 'index.php?r=branches/upload',
           'maxFilesize' => '2',
           'addRemoveLinks' =>true,
            'acceptedFiles' =>'image/*',    


             ],
       'clientEvents' => [
           'complete' => "function(file){console.log(file)}",
          // 'removedfile' => "function(file){alert(file.name + ' is removed')}"
           'removedfile' => "function(file){
             alert('Delete this file?');
          $.ajax({
               url: 'index.php?r=branches/rmf',
               type: 'GET',
               data: { 'filetodelete': file.name}
          });

           }"
       ],
   ]);
?>
```

Comment: Hi Can you add the generated script code

Answer (score 2):

This plugin use `Json::encode` function for encoding options and because of this, in your code `init` encode as string. String is not a **function**.

You can simply use [JsExpression](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-jsexpression.html) for `javascript` function to prevent this.

> When using yii\helpers\Json::encode() or
>   yii\helpers\Json::htmlEncode() to encode a value, JsonExpression
>   objects will be specially handled and encoded as a **JavaScript**
>   **expression** **instead of a string**.

This code should work.

```
<?= \kato\DropZone::widget([
        'autoDiscover' => false,
       'options' => [
         'init' => new JsExpression("function(file){alert( ' is removed')}"),
         'url'=> 'index.php?r=branches/upload',
           'maxFilesize' => '2',
           'addRemoveLinks' =>true,
            'acceptedFiles' =>'image/*',    


             ],
       'clientEvents' => [
           'complete' => "function(file){console.log(file)}",
          // 'removedfile' => "function(file){alert(file.name + ' is removed')}"
           'removedfile' => "function(file){
             alert('Delete this file?');
          $.ajax({
               url: 'index.php?r=branches/rmf',
               type: 'GET',
               data: { 'filetodelete': file.name}
          });

           }"
       ],    ]); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

it looks like this part in your options overwrites the Dropzone.js `init` function:

```
'init' => "function(file){alert( ' is removed')}",
```

The Yii2 plugin you are using ist simply encoding the options array:

```
Json::encode($this->options)
```

So your init is no `function` it is a `string` like this:

```
var options = { "init" : "function(file){alert( ' is removed')}" }
```

<del>It is not possible to set the `init` option over this php plugin.</del>

---

**Edit:** Thanks @CooPer for the correction, Yii2 isn't my favourite framework so I'm not very familiar with it. It's a good solution.